# DPDK: Most efficient way to modify captured packet's headers

Tags: c++, network-programming, packet, dpdk

i'm trying to modify headers of some GTP packets using the mbuf and mempool libraries, specifically i want to cut out all of ETH, IP, UDP ,GTP layers and **obtain a (deep) copy of the packet's payload**.

Here's the piece of code that should do the work:

```
void (const unsigned char* packet, size_t size)
{
    auto outer_header_len = sizeof(ether_header) + sizeof(ip) + sizeof(udphdr) + sizeof(gtp); //length to cut
    uint8_t byte_size = static_cast<uint8_t>(size);
    struct rte_mempool* mbuf_pool;

    struct rte_mbuf *mbuf_pkt = rte_pktmbuf_alloc(mbuf_pool);
    mbuf_pkt->data_len = byte_size;
    mbuf_pkt->pkt_len = byte_size;

    rte_pktmbuf_append(mbuf_pkt, packet[byte_size]);    
    auto payload = rte_pktmbuf_adj(mbuf_pkt, outer_header_len);
}
```

This function is called from a loop which parses the stream of packets and passes *packet* and *size* at each iteration. Since there will be lots of calls, how can i make my code memory efficient and better? Any tips?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are few issues with the code.

#### byte_size

`uint8_t byte_size = static_cast<uint8_t>(size);` I am not sure that is correct, since it basically limiting all packets to 256 bytes, which might not be always the case. So I would just deleted this line, since the `size` itself is a perfectly fine.

#### rte_pktmbuf_append()

`rte_pktmbuf_append(mbuf_pkt, packet[byte_size]);` this function increases the length of `mbuf_pkt`, but do not change the mbuf bytes themselves. So we have to use the pointer it returns to actually do the copy, i.e.

```
ptr = rte_pktmbuf_append(mbuf_pkt, size);
if (ptr != NULL)
    rte_memcpy(ptr, packet + outer_header_len, size -outer_header_len);
```

Here are also the links to the [rte_pktmbuf_append()](http://dpdk.org/doc/api/rte__mbuf_8h.html#ad5b0cd686ad3bcbb83416ca8395a080b) and [rte_memcpy()](http://dpdk.org/doc/api/rte__memcpy_8h.html#a09f4d8cdb1a7c25398a363906e1db8cd) documentation.

#### Other Mbuf Length Manipulations

Since the `rte_pktmbuf_append()` increases the length of the packet, the following lines are redundant:

```
mbuf_pkt->data_len = byte_size;
mbuf_pkt->pkt_len = byte_size;
auto payload = rte_pktmbuf_adj(mbuf_pkt, outer_header_len);
```

#### Performance

We can copy data without the outer header by taking into account `outer_header_len` during the data copy as in the example before:

```
ptr = rte_pktmbuf_append(mbuf_pkt, size);
if (ptr != NULL)
    rte_memcpy(ptr, packet + outer_header_len, size -outer_header_len);
```

A check if the `outer_header_len` is less than the packet length might be also required, unless there is such a check made earlier in the code.